I can not load dwplot, modelsummary and sjPLot in R
I am trying to load some package in R but with no success. This is what I get
 install.packages("dotwhisker")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Nick/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.wu.ac.at/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/dotwhisker_0.8.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 309957 bytes (302 KB)
downloaded 302 KB

package ‘dotwhisker’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpe2ha0y\downloaded_packages

> library(dotwhisker)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dotwhisker’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘insight’ 0.20.5 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required

Another function
library(sjPlot)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sjPlot’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘insight’ 0.20.5 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required

Another function:
 library(modelsummary)  # model plot
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘modelsummary’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'modelsummary', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: lazy-load database 'C:/Users/Nick/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/insight/R/insight.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In fun(libname, pkgname) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In fun(libname, pkgname) :
  internal error 1 in R_decompress1 with libdeflate

I also tried  update.packages()   but with no success.
I have the lastest version of R.
Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

Start a clean R session (no .Rprofile etc). Make sure you have nothing but core packages loaded. Then install.packages(“ insight”). Then try again.

It worked!. Many thanks!
